# how to return shape from mouse event evt.currentTarget.children[0]

Tags: mouseevent, createjs

```
var stage, output;

function init() {
    stage = new createjs.Stage("testCanvas");

    // this lets our drag continue to track the mouse even when it leaves the canvas:
    // play with commenting this out to see the difference.
    stage.mouseMoveOutside = true; 


    var circle = new createjs.Shape();
    circle.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100,20,10);
    //console.log(circle.graphics.command.radius);

    var label = new createjs.Text("drag me", "bold 14px Arial", "#FFFFFF");
    label.textAlign = "center";
    label.y = -7;

    var dragger = new createjs.Container();
    dragger.x = 50;
    dragger.y = 10;
    dragger.addChild(circle, label);
    stage.addChild(dragger);

    dragger.on("pressmove",function(evt) {
        // currentTarget will be the container that the event listener was added to:
        //evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
        //evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;
        // make sure to redraw the stage to show the change:
        //console.log(evt.currentTarget.children[0].graphics.command);
        var newWidth=  evt.stageX - evt.currentTarget.x;
        console.log(evt.currentTarget.children[0].graphics);
        if(newWidth<0)
            newWidth = 0; 
        evt.currentTarget.children[0].graphics.command.w= newWidth;
        evt.currentTarget.children[1].x= newWidth/2;
        stage.update();   
    });

    stage.update();
}
```

this code is working fine under http://www.createjs.com/demos

(i can reach this evt.currentTarget.children[0].graphics.command.w, because evt.currentTarget.children[0] returns shape)
but not on your own html. it is there any js i need to add in the heading?

Comment: You should inspect the function when it gets called using the debugger, and determine what is under the mouse. The approach you are using to look up the child, as well as change the width is not ideal - and makes a lot of assumptions about what the structure of the display list is like.

What is your console log outputting?

Answer (score -1):

Did you checked if "pressmove" trigger?

Maybe you should use this `stage.enableMouseOver(20);` to enable mouse events.